# django foriegn key IntegrityError: myapp_model2.name_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

```
class Model1(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)

class Model2(models.Model):
     name = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
     unique_str = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
```

I've already filled 3 sample username-password in Model1 through django-admin page

In my views I'm getting this list as

```
userlist = Model1.objects.all()
#print userlist[0].username, userlist[0].password

for user in userlist:
     a,b = Model2.objects.get_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67')
     a.name = user
     a.city = "acity"
     a.save()
```

but Traceback is showing me error at line 
`a,b = Model2.objects.get_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67')`

`IntegrityError: myapp_model2.name_id may not be NULL`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `null=True` in your foreign_key field "name" in your Model2 to allow its model to be instantiated without a value, otherwise when you're calling get_or_create without a name defined, it raises the IntegrityError because at the time the object gets created it doesn't have a name (user) defined **yet**.

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Model1, null=True)
```

You can also set the name directly when calling get_or_create :

```
a,b = Model2.objects.get_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67', name=user)
```

Depending on the way you're planning on creating these objects, you might also need to add `blank=True` to permit empty values in form validation.

---

See [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) for more info on this and other field / model options you might find interesting :)

HTH !

Comment: Are you still setting `a.name = user` and then `a.save()` ?

Comment: It does exist : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#unique-together :) Although from what I understand you're trying to create a "lighter" version of the User model, aren't you ? You should look into using it directly.